# gensim word2vec giving inconsistent results

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

i am using gensim in ubuntu. version is 0.12.4. my word2vec model is not consistent. every time i build the model based on the same exact sentences and same parameter it still have different presentations of the words.

here is the code (that i stole from the initial post)

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> from gensim.models import Word2Vec
>>> sentences = brown.sents()[:100]
>>> model = Word2Vec(sentences, size=10, window=5, min_count=5, workers=4)
>>> model[sentences[0][0]]
array([ 0.04913874,  0.04574081, -0.07402877, -0.03270053,  0.06598952,
        0.04157289,  0.05075986,  0.01770534, -0.03796235,  0.04594197], dtype=float32)
>>> model = Word2Vec(sentences, size=10, window=5, min_count=5, workers=4)
>>> model[sentences[0][0]]
array([ 0.04907205,  0.04569579, -0.07379777, -0.03273782,  0.06579078,
        0.04167712,  0.05083019,  0.01780009, -0.0378389 ,  0.04578455], dtype=float32)
>>> model = Word2Vec(sentences, size=10, window=5, min_count=5, workers=4)
>>> model[sentences[0][0]]
array([ 0.04906179,  0.04569826, -0.07382379, -0.03274316,  0.06583244,
        0.04166647,  0.0508585 ,  0.01777468, -0.03784611,  0.04578935], dtype=float32)
```

I have also tried to set seed to some fixed int but this didnt seem to help. i also tried to reinstall gensim which also didnt help.

Any idea how to stabilize my model??

Comment: If I might, the instability you notice is not sufficient enough to propagate to any significant error. Changes in the third or fourth decimal place are always small enough to be ignored. Note also that `float32` (in fact all floating point values) exhibit loss of precision - it's a tradeoff between being able to store the level of precision you see in the first place.

Comment: the difference can actually be significant. the example i posted uses very small amount of data. You can stabilize the model by using 1 worker only and this will give consistent results

Comment: Really? What was the maximum difference you observed? Could be very useful to know.

Comment: Word2Vec default random seed is set to 1 already - https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec. The inconsistency you are getting looks like precision difference only

Answer (score 0):

Try to set PYTHONHASHSEED environment variable  as stated here
https://github.com/gojomo/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/doc2vec.py#L566